# Angular: ng-if animation not working on directive

Tags: angularjs, animate.css

I'm using Angular 1.3 and [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

I'm trying to apply a simple fadeIn/out animation on a directive i have using this code:

```
.vl-fade-in-out{
    &.ng-enter{
        animation: fadeIn 1s;
    }

    &.ng-leave{
        animation:  fadeOut 1s;
    }

}
```

But no animation is applied, however, the same animation does apply if i use it directly on a html element (like div).

```
//this is not animating
<my-directive class="vl-fade-in-out" ng-if="show"></my-directive>
//this is animating
<div class="vl-fade-in-out" ng-if="show"></div>
```

Also if i apply fadeIn/out effect using transition it works even when applied on the directive:

```
.vl-fade-in-out{
    &.ng-enter{
        transition:1s linear all;
        opacity: 0;

        &.ng-enter-active{
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    &.ng-leave{
            transition:1s linear all;
            opacity: 1;
        &.ng-leave-active{
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }


}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOLzGE

Comment: the class is being assigned to the directive element, which can't be animated, rather than the `<p>` that is in the template.

Comment: that being said, it seems to animate properly in IE but not in Chrome, which is probably due to the differences in the way that the browsers deal with unrecognized HTML elements.

Comment: @Claies - but , as I noted in the last part of my question ,transition does work

Answer (score 1):

@Claies was right in his second comment.

`<my-directive>` is not a recognized element in Chrome so it does not assign it **any** default attributes that you would expect. Assigning `display: block` to `my-directive` or `.vl-fade-in-out` will allow it to be animated.

Or you could use `replace: true` in the `myDirective` return in order to replace the custom element with the content of the template if your content contains a normal element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `restrict:'C'` with `<div class="test">`. it will work